# Write as a single trigonometric function: $\dfrac{2\tan4θ}{5-5\tan^24θ}$

Tags: trigonometry

> Write as a single trigonometric function: $\dfrac{2\tan4θ}{5-5\tan^24θ}$

I got $5\tan8θ$, is this correct? If not I'd appreciate the proper way of doing it, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{2\tan4\theta}{1-{\tan}^2 4\theta}\right)$

=$\frac15 \tan(2(4\theta))$

=$\frac{\tan8\theta}{5}$

Comment: Thank you :) I like the way you did it.